# Setting videoCompostion of AVItemPlayer rotates video

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, avfoundation

I have to apply filters on videos on playback, to do so I tried to use `AVVideoComposition`, Specifically [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avmutablevideocomposition/1387006-videocompositionwithasset?language=objc)

However, when I set this composition to my `playerItem` the video rotates completely. By rotate I mean the width becomes the height and vice versa and so the image stretches.

How can I prevent my video from rotating ?

NOTE: When I put the app in the background by clicking on home button, and then open it again I get the correct result.

Comment: What exactly is your question with this?

Comment: See new version now please.